# GitLab Maintenance Notes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab server running and want to install runners. However, when I get to registering the runners they fail. On the "optional maintenance note" step, I press enter to skip that step and I get an error and then it quits the registering session.

How would I get that to work? Or at least so that I can skip that step without failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not the maintenance notes failing. After the maintenance notes, the runner registers with the git-lab server. What was failing was a cache error on the git-lab server itself.

Run these commands to clear those:

```
gitlab-rails dbconsole --database main
UPDATE projects SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
UPDATE namespaces SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
UPDATE application_settings SET encrypted_ci_jwt_signing_key = null;
UPDATE ci_runners SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
exit
```